# Pass {(ngModel)} through components in *ngFor

Tags: angular, search, ngfor, ngmodel

how can i pass a {(ngModel)} in a other component to use in a *ngFor?
I have a navbar with a input to search and im using ng2-search-filter, i need to pass the {(ngModel)} in a other component (the table with the results) but i cant.

#### Template: `app.component.html`

```html
    <div [@routeAnimations]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''" class="main-content">
      <app-navbar></app-navbar>
      <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

#### Template: `navbar.component.html`

```html
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Sarch" type="text" name="filter" [(ngModel)]="stringToLook">
```

#### Template: `table.component.html`

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let object of (objects$ | async) | filter:filter | paginate: config | orderBy: key : reverse">
```

filter:stringToLook dont work (stringToLook is Undefined).

---

#### Component: `table.component.ts`

```js
    .....
        @Input() stringToLook: any;
    .....
```

### UPDATE

I read the doc and i did it but dont work.

#### Parent Component

`html`

```
<form (submit)="setText(filter.value)" >
            <input class="form-control" name="filter" placeholder="Cerca" type="text" #filter>
            <button type="submit" style="display:none">hidden submit</button>
          </form>
```

`ts`

```
filter: string;
setText(filter: string) {
  this.filter = filter;
  console.log(this.filter);
  }
```

#### Child Component

`ts`

```
@Input('filter') filter: string;
```

Thanks so much

Comment: whats the relation in between the filter and the table?

Comment: Did you check whether it's the `filter` value that isn't passed correctly, or is it the `filter` _pipe_ that doesn't do what you expect it to do? In other words: in the `... | filter:filter | ...` fragment, is the problem with the left `filter`, or with the right `filter`?

Comment: @GaryB is the text to search

Comment: @mbojko Right filter.

Comment: Sorry I meant the components, navbar and table

Comment: navbar is loaded before of table.component, navbar should pass the string of the input to table.component.html to use ng2-search-filter with filter:"string" in *ngFor, ng2-search-filter filters the content based on the string content.

Comment: @GaryB do you have some idea?

Comment: 1.) Input passing data from child to parent, if table is not the parent then never get the data.
2.) you have to pass the data thru this tag <app-navbar></app-navbar> eg: [somethingToPass]="this.ValuePassed"
the question is still there, whats the relation in between the two components?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you, because I told you before. Navbar.Component have to pass the input text [(ngModel)]="stringToLook" from the user to the Table.Component, check the code up, now should be cleaner, filter:stringToLook , filter is from a external component called ng2-search-filter, it work like this filter:"STRING", stringToLook is the string to look in a table, without this string don't work, i have to take the string from the input (navbar.component) and use it in the component table.component

Comment: Hi Toriga, I believe what GaryB is trying to establish is whether you have any parent child relationship between your components as you are trying access properties of one from another. As you haven't shared with us the entire code snippet its difficult for us to derive this information. In a parent child relationship, properties are sent down in the template declaration tag.

Comment: Please see angular's official documentation on component interaction https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction and see if its of any help or tell us a bit more detail how your components are defined or share your ts and html files of the two components in their entirety so we can see the big picture to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed using a service, in the service i create the variable String and a Setter,in parent component i set the value and in child component i get the value.

#### Service

```
filter: string;
setText(filter: string) {
    this.filter = filter;
    console.log(this.filter);
  }
```

#### Parent

`Html`

```
<form (submit)="service.setText(filter.value)" >
            <input class="form-control" name="filter" placeholder="Cerca" type="text" #filter>
            <button type="submit" style="display:none">hidden submit</button>
          </form>
```

`TS`
constructor(..., private service: Service)

#### Child

Simply when you need, use service.filter

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we want to share data across components, services are the best choice.

I will recommend you to use a more asynchronous way for getting and setting data from your service using rxjs observables and subjects.

For more: [angular-8-communication-between-components-using-subject-and-observable](https://jsonworld.com/demo/angular-8-communication-between-components-using-subject-and-observable)

Service

```
_filter = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
filter$ = this._filter.asObservable();
```

Component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.service.filter$.subscribe(x => this.filter = x);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

onChangeFilter(filterNewValue: any) {
  this.service._filter.next(filterNewValue)
}
```

Comment: @Toriga as u can see, now the filter on your component will have the value that you want. If another compontent change that value u automatically get the right value in all your components that have subscribe to the observable

Comment: But the code of component goes either to parent component and child component?